# Can we use 2 shipping method in 1 checkout?

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-methods

Want to develop functionality like user can select different shipping methods for product in checkout. I want to use 2 shipping methods for one order , is that possible?

Comment: Yes , you can add one field in the table and store it in the order of object data.

Comment: @Msquare do you have any module or code?

Comment: You need to check where the shipping method is stored and debug it, then copy the same process for your second shipping method.

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 has multi-address Shipping options this allows the customers to ship an order to multiple addresses during checkout.

Enable this feature.

Is it that the address will be same but products will be shipped using two different shipping methods.
This will need a split order module that will split and order into multiple orders on order confirmation.